# MATLAB code doesn't work when I run it as a loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, eval

I'm assigning some files to variables in MATLAB. I'm a little lazy and *trying* to maybe demonstrate a little problem-solving, so I tried to write a function to do this. The body of the function:

```
i=0
for i=0:8
    eval(sprintf('C%d=wavread([''C'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('Cs%d=wavread([''Cs'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('D%d=wavread([''D'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('Ef%d=wavread([''Ef'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('E%d=wavread([''E'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('F%d=wavread([''F'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('Fs%d=wavread([''Fs'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('G%d=wavread([''G'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('Af%d=wavread([''Af'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('A%d=wavread([''A'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('Bf%d=wavread([''Bf'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    eval(sprintf('B%d=wavread([''B'' num2str(i)]);', i));
    i=i+1
end
```

Everything's hunky dory when I just assign a value to i and run the code within the loop, but when I actually run it as a loop, it'll just run to completion without returning any variables.

Any ideas why?

**Thanks y'all! Also figured out why my function didn't return anything! Stupid mistake :)**

Comment: replace all your `eval` with `disp` and run the loop and see what's wrong with the code you are generating. This is the best way to see what's going wrong when using `eval`, but you should almost definitely not be using `eval`

Comment: Instead of `eval` you should make a cell array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099398/matlab-create-variables-with-names-from-strings/16099569#16099569

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because `eval` generates its own workspace, so whilst the variables are being created, they are then lost at the end of the `eval` call, a bit like the way variables created inside a function are lost when it returns.  I suggest you do this the 'proper' way and use cell arrays instead:

```
i = 0; % Note: uneccessary line!
for i = 0:8
    C{i + 1} = wavread(['C' num2str(i)]);
    Cs{i + 1} = wavread(['Cs' num2str(i)]);
    D{i + 1} = wavread(['D' num2str(i)]);
    Ef{i + 1} = wavread(['Ef' num2str(i)]);
    E{i + 1} = wavread(['E' num2str(i)]);
    F{i + 1} = wavread(['F' num2str(i)]);
    Fs{i + 1} = wavread(['Fs' num2str(i)]);
    G{i + 1} = wavread(['G' num2str(i)]);
    Af{i + 1} = wavread(['Af' num2str(i)]);
    A{i + 1} = wavread(['A' num2str(i)]);
    Bf{i + 1} = wavread(['Bf' num2str(i)]);
    B{i + 1} = wavread(['B' num2str(i)]);
    i = i+1;  % Note: uneccessary line!
end
```

**EDIT:**  Ignore what I said about `eval`, see Dan's comment below.  Nonetheless, a cell array is the appropriate way to tackle this.

Comment: I think you are wrong about `eval`, it can definitely create variables. But this is the correct way to go. It just must not be in a function, or that function must return all the variables.

Comment: You're right, it can.  I was slightly jumping to conclusions after OP said "without returning any variables", but he obviously didn't mean that they didn't exist in the workspace.

Comment: No I think he does mean that, they won't exist in the workspace but not because of eval, because he's made a function that doesn't return them (i suspect). But +1 for the cell arrays

Answer (score 0):

If your code is the body of a function as you have said, then the code generated by `eval` will be scoped to that function. As soon as the function returns, the variables are released. The code posted by jazzbassrob will also not work if it's in a function, but it is definitely the correct way to go. Just make it a script and not a function. Or even better, make the function return the cell arrays:

```
function [C, Cs, ...] = readWavs()
    for ii = 0:8
        C{ii} = wavread(['C' num2str(ii)]);
        ....
        ii = ii + 1 %NB this line makes no sense! i will increment by 1 anyway because of the for loop. If you want to increment by 2 then you should change the loop to for ii = 0:2:8
    end
end
```

Or a struct of the cell arrays:

```
function wavStruct = readWavs()
    for ii = 0:8
        wavStruct{ii}.C = wavread(['C' num2str(ii)]);
        ...
    end
end
```

Also it's best not to use `i` or `j` as variable names in matlab as they are reserved for `sqrt(-1)`, hence I've used `ii`