# Can you call a matrix from a string

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix, call, strcat

I have to make a call to read in a matrix with a name that is created from a strcat, in Matlab. For example

```
person = 2;
Index_XNY = strcat('Index_X',num2str(person),'Y');

Big_Index = find(Index_XNY(1,:)==1);
```

This works if I replace Index_XNY with Index_X2Y for this example.

I have tried a number of different things to obtain Big_Index, but so far I have not been successful. Can this be done, as there is a large collection of data elements that need to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) function to evaluate a Matlab expression in a string:

```
expr = strcat('find(Index_X',num2str(person),'Y(1,:)==1)');
Big_Index = eval(expr);
```

Of course, a lot of alternative ways to do this with `eval` function exist, depending on how much you would like to put into the string and how much would be left out.

Comment: Perfect, I was using eval, but I did not create the overall command and call it. It is so obvious now, thank you Xiaolei for your help!

Comment: @Levz You should strongly consider make a cell array instead of separately naming your variables. This would alleviate the need for `eval` which is difficult to debug and generally considered bad practice.

Comment: @Dan Thanks you Dan, I'm not sure what you mean by separately naming the variables, but it will give me something to research. Do you know of an example I could look at?

Comment: @Levz [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099398/matlab-create-variables-with-names-from-strings/16099569#16099569). Basically instead of having multiple variables called Index_X1Y and Index_X2Y etc you should just have a single cell array and use it like Index_XY{1} and Index_XY{2} etc...