# Javascript create n number of variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I have an array

```
    var n = ["Joe", "Peter", "Mary", "Chris", "Dave", "Sally", "Pat", "John", "Larry", "Andrew"];
```

And I want to create a variable for each of the strings in the array, i.e.

```
    var Joe;
    var Peter;
    var Mary;
```

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099398/create-variables-with-names-from-strings) for MatLab, but is there some way of doing this with Javascript?

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDgd6/1/) of how I would think of doing it but obviously it doesn't work!

Comment: why? this just complicates things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...is there some way of doing this with Javascript?

<s>Not in the generic case, no.</s> *(Ugh, see below.)* You can do it with *global* variables, like this:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < n.length; ++index) {
    window[n[index]] = /*...whatever value you want the global to have...*/;
}
```

...but that only works for globals (and `window` is specific to the browser environment, although it's possible to do something analogous outside browsers), and barring some really specific reason for doing it, it's not a good idea.

You can create an object with properties for each of those names:

```
var obj = {};
var index;
for (index = 0; index < n.length; ++index) {
    obj[n[index]] = /*...whatever value you want the global to have...*/;
}
```

...which is basically the global variable case, but with an object and not globals. But again, unless you have a really good reason to do it, there's little point (although it's not as harmful as creating a bunch of globals).

---

Okay, that's not *quite* true. You can do it like this:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < n.length; ++index) {
    eval("var " + n[index]);
}
```

That will actually create variables in the current scope with the names from `n`. I don't recommend it. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't say it can't be done, but an object is certainly the better alternative.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Ugh, you're right. `eval` Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't suggest doing that, but it would be possible by using:

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<n.length; i++) {
    window[n[i]] = ...;
}
```

I would suggest wrapping them in an object using:

```
var i, holder = {};
for(i=0; i<n.length; i++) {
    holder [n[i]] = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an associative array. So it might look something like this:

```
var array = {
     "John": 1,
     "Mary": 284
};
```

Then you would reference the value via `array["John"]` and would get 1 back.

Comment: They're called "objects" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a object like this:

```
var names = {
    Joe: "...",
    Mary: "...",
    // etc...
}
```

And access:

`names.Joe`