# How to convert a string into a variable name in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, variables, mapping

I want to do the following in MATLAB:

```
dang = 1000;
jam = 'dang';
groo = str2var(jam);
```

This should give me `groo = 1000`. How do I do this?

Reason: I have a workspace that contains large integer array variables named like this: `var1`, `var2`, ..., `var4500`. I want to be able to use an iterative method to generate the variable names and the only way I can think of doing this is by concatenating strings in a for loop ('var' 'number'), and using those strings as variable names.

Comment: You would need [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) for that. But it's bad practice. As it is having separatte variables `var1`, `var2` etc. Use a numeric array or a cell array instead

Comment: you can also use a structure with dynamic field. As an example: `for ii=1:10 ; MyStruct.(['var' num2str(ii)]) ; end`, but you can build the string the way you like. Look at the Matlab doc [generate-field-names-from-variables](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html). Your question has already been asked though, you can lookup the different answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099398/create-variables-with-names-from-strings)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but eval lets me convert a variable into a string, not the other way round. Yeah, using a structure  may be the way to go.