# Looping a process, outputting numerically labelled variables each time

Tags: matlab

I have about 50 different arrays and I want to perform the following operation on all of them:

```
data1(isnan(data1)) = 0;   
coldata1 = nonzeros(data1);   
avgdata1 = mean(coldata1);
```

and so on for `data2`, `data3` etc... the goal being to turn `data1` into a vector without `NaN`s and then take a mean, saving the vector and the mean into `coldata1` and `avgdata1`.

I'm looking for a way to automate this for all 50, rather than copy it 50 times and change the numbers... any ideas? I've been playing with `eval` but no luck so far. Also tried:

```
for y = 1:50
    data(y)(isnan(data(y))) = 0;
    coldata(y) = nonzeros(data(y));   
    avgdata(y) = mean(coldata(y)); 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `eval` but really should not. Rather use a cell array as suggested here: [Create variables with names from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099398/create-variables-with-names-from-strings/16099569#16099569)

i.e.

```
for y = 1:50
    data{y}(isnan(data{y})) = 0;
    coldata{y} = nonzeros(data{y});   
    avgdata{y} = mean(coldata{y}); 
end
```

Also read [How can I create variables A1, A2,...,A10 in a loop?](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F) for alternative options.