# How to use a dynamic string variable in an XPath expression in matlab

Tags: matlab, xpath

I'm trying to find the children of a specific node (concept) of an XMl document in matlab using Xpath.
I used the following code I get 5 children which is true.

```
expression  = xpath.compile('//concept\[@name="con1"\]/\*');
Childs      = expression.evaluate(xDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

But for my project I have to use the string values of the attributes "name" of each concept in dynamic manner, so I stored them in  vector in order to cal them one by one.
For example, `ConceptName(1)="con1"`, however, when I execute the following code, I get zero children:

```
expression = xpath.compile('//concept\[@name="ConceptName(1)"\]/\*');
Childs     = expression.evaluate(xDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

If there is someone who can help me to call the sting variables to the path expression I would be very grateful.
Thank you in advance.

Here is how my XML doc look like, My desired outpout whould be a list of four concepts (the first children of the concept which has the name="con1"), but I must extract the name of the parent concept dynamicly because the structure whould be unkowen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taxonomy>
    <concept name="con1">
        <concept name="con11">
            <concept name="con1033990258">
                <concept name="con271874239">
                    <concept name="con1657241849">
                        <concept name="con1448945150"> 
                            <instance name="inst686829093"/>
                            <instance name="inst1379512917"/>
                            <instance name="inst2072196703"/>
                        </concept>
                   </concept>
              </concept>
        </concept>
        <concept name="con12"> </concept>
        <concept name="con13"></concept>
        <concept name="con14"></concept>
    </concept>
</taxonomy>
```

This is my code

```
% get the xpath mechanism into the workspace
import javax.xml.xpath.*
factory     = XPathFactory.newInstance;
xpath       = factory.newXPath;

% read the XML file
filedir      = 'C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Asma\MatlabCode\Contribution2\WSC2009_XML'; %location of the file
files        = dir(fullfile(filedir, '*.xml'));
xDoc         = xmlread(fullfile(filedir, files(1).name)); % read  the XML doc but return "[#document: null]". The xmlread function returns a Java object that represents the file's Document Object Model, or DOM. The "null" is simply what the org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl's implementation of toString() dumps to the MATLAB Command Window
XDocInMatlab = xmlwrite(xDoc); % show the XML file


taxonomy     = xDoc.getElementsByTagName('taxonomy'); %% get the root elment
concepts     = xDoc.getElementsByTagName('concept'); %% get the concept elemnt node 

concept_Matrix = strings(concepts.getLength,1); 

for i = 0 : concepts.getLength-1
   
    conceptName           = string(concepts.item(i).getAttribute('name'));
    concept_Matrix(i+1,1) = conceptName;
    
  
   

    if concepts.item(i).hasChildNodes
        expression   =   xpath.compile('//concept[@name=conceptName]/*');
        Childs =   expression.evaluate(xDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        % Iterate through the nodes that are returned.
 
        for j = 0:Childs.getLength-1
          ChildsName(j+1) = char(Childs.item(j).getAttribute('name'));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create variables with names from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099398/create-variables-with-names-from-strings)

Comment: @Irreducible I don't think that that is the answer. Rather, it looks like the OP wants to parse raw XML into MATLAB (struct/cell/array whatever way to store them), not create separate variables.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to clarify what the desired output is? Just a list/table/struct/cell/whatever with the names `"con11", "con2"` etc?

Comment: My desired outpou whould be a list of four concepts (the first children of the concept which has the name="con1"), but I must extract the name of the parent concept dynamicly because the structure whould be unkowen. So how can I do that. Thank you.

Comment: thank you @Irreducible  by the lik that you gave me doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 0):

The expression `@name="ConceptName(1)"` doesn't select anything because you don't have any elements whose name attribute has the value "ConceptName(1)".

It's hard to know how to correct your code because you don't really tell us what you thought it might mean. You say you stored the attribute names "in a vector" but there's no such thing as a vector in XPath, so I really don't know what you did or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you want people to help debug your code, you will need to show your code, in sufficient details so people can reproduce the failure.

Comment: I stored the name attributes of all concepts in vector like ConceptNameVector=["con1","con11","con1033990258","con271874239","con1657241849","con1448945150","con12","con13","con14"]  in order to use them in dynamic manner in the Xpath expression. Howver when I call for example  ConceptNameVector(1) in The path expression I get 0 child although ConceptNameVector(1) returns "con1" wich is désired value. Thank you in advance or taking the time to anser me back. Respectefully.

Comment: I showed my code in the answers, I hope that would my question clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to replace the following line

```
expression = xpath.compile('//concept\[@name="ConceptName(1)"\]/\*')
```

with something like this:

```
expression = xpath.compile('//concept\[@name="' + ConceptName(1) + '"\]/\*')
```

Note that this works only if `ConceptName` is a string array type (with double quotes), not a char vector (single quotes).

Note also that it is not necessary to escape square brackets and asterisks in strings:

```
expression = xpath.compile('//concept[@name="' + ConceptName(1) + '"]/*')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Cris Luengo, it's works but without the slaches "/"   like this                                                                                 expression = xpath.compile('//concept[@name="' + conceptName(1) + '"]/*').                                      Can you pleas suggest me how can I extract the XML information in the form of tree as I asek in my second post  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585858/nested-xml-file-in-matlab. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: @Asma Sorry, I don't know anything about XPath, so cannot help you with your other question.